# Конструктор перемещения не вызывается

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, перемещение

Есть такой класс

```
 class A
 {
 public:
    A(): _size(0), _value(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "A() "<< this << std::endl;
    }
    A(const int size) : _size( size ), _value( new char[size] )
    {
        std::cout << "A( const int ) " << this << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
            _value[i] = 'a' + i;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A() " << this << std::endl;
        if (_value)
           delete[] _value;
    }

    A( A&& a ):_size(0), _value(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "A( A&& ) "<< this << std::endl;
    
        std::swap( _size, a._size );
        std::swap( _value, a._value );
    }

    A& operator=( A&& a )
    {
         std::cout << "operator=( A&& ) "<< this << std::endl;

        std::swap( _size, a._size );
        std::swap( _value, a._value );
     
        return *this;
    }

    A( const A& a)
    {
         std::cout << "A( A& ) "<< this << std::endl;

        _size = a._size;
        _value = new char[_size];

        memcpy( _value, a._value, sizeof( char ) * _size );
    }
    A& operator=( const A& a)
    {
         std::cout << "operator=( const A& ) " << this << std::endl;
    
        _size = a._size;

        if (_value)
            delete _value;

        _value = new char[_size];

        memcpy( _value, a._value, sizeof( char ) * _size );
        return *this;
    }

 private:
    int _size; 
    char* _value;
 };
```

И пара функций

```
A f1(int size)
{
    return A(size);
}

A foo( A&& a )
{
    return A( a );
}
```

При выполнении этого кода:

```
 int main()
 {
      A a2 = foo( f1( 5 ) );
      return 0;
 }
```

вывод следующий:

```
 A( const int ) 0050F6E4
 A( A& ) 0050F7B4
 ~A() 0050F6E4
 ~A() 0050F7B4
```

То есть перемещающий конструктор не вызывается. Вопрос почему и как сделать чтобы вызывался?

Comment: В каком месте тут по-вашему должен вызываться этот конструктор?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
A foo( A&& a )
{
    return A( move(a) );
}
```

Потому как аргумент `a`, несмотря на объявление как `A&&`, внутри функции является lvalue - у него есть адрес. А `move` делает из него таки `rvalue`.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*